# In Scala, can I call Source.reset() on resources read from the classpath?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a jarfile on my classpath. In that jarfile I have a file `afile.txt`.

I need to iterate on that file twice, once to count the lines and once to parse it. This is what I did:

```
val source = Source.fromInputStream(/*some magic to get the resource's InputStream*/)
source.getLines.foreach (/*count the lines*/)
source.getLines.reset.foreach (/*do something interesting*/)
```

But this doesn't work. In the debugger it looks like the call to `reset()` returns an empty iterator. The code above works fine when the Source refers to a file on the filesystem instead of on the classpath.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Scala's io library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug is the Scala library. I had a quick look at Source.scala in [2.8 trunk](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/io/Source.scala?rev=22460) and reset seems to return a new wrapper around the original input stream which would have no content left after the first pass. I think it should throw an exception. I can't think of a straightforward way you could reset an arbitrary input stream.

I think you can simply call `val source2 = Source.fromInputStream` and read again, as it seems `reset` does not do more than that.